# How can I supply a numeric argument to a Readline function e.g. `glob-expand-word`?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, gnu, readline

How can I supply an argument to a Readline function, e.g. `glob-expand-word` that is bound to `C-x *` by default?

In this case, I want to supply a numeric argument to make append an asterisk to the word before the cursor.

`man bash`:

> glob-expand-word (C-x *)
>
> The  word  before  point is treated as a pattern for pathname expansion, and the list of matching filenames is inserted, replacing the word.  If a numeric argument is supplied, an asterisk is appended
> before pathname expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric arguments can be supplied to Readline functions using `M-0, M-1,...`, where `M--` starts a negative numeric argument.

Furthermore, the `universal-argument` function, optionally bound to `C-u` (see below), also makes it possible to supply numeric arguments to command by executing the function and then pressing a sequence of digits, optionally with a leading minus sign:

```
          "\C-u": universal-argument
```

`man bash` (exerpt):

```
   Numeric Arguments
       digit-argument (M-0, M-1, ..., M--)
              Add this digit to the argument already accumulating, or start a new argument.  M-- starts a negative argument.
       universal-argument
              This is another way to specify an argument.  If this command is followed by one or more digits, optionally with a leading minus sign, those digits define the argument.  If the command is  followed  by
              digits,  executing  universal-argument again ends the numeric argument, but is otherwise ignored.  As a special case, if this command is immediately followed by a character that is neither a digit nor
              minus sign, the argument count for the next command is multiplied by four.  The argument count is initially one, so executing this function the first time makes the argument count four, a second  time
              makes the argument count sixteen, and so on.
```